# Lifetimes when Deserializing JSON within a FromForm

Tags: rust, serde, rust-rocket

I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the lifetimes on this code. Basically, I have a Rocket API that receives some `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, with only one key: `json`. This key contains, intuitively, a JSON value, encoded with percent-encoding, of a struct `Message<T>`.

(I'm aware this is suboptimal API design, but this is reverse-engineering work, so I have no option)

To be easily used as a request guard as `From<Message<T>>`, I'm implementing `FromForm`. To do that, I need to implement `FromForm<'f>` for any `Message<T>` where `T` implements `Deserialize<'de>`. I wrote my impl signature as `impl<'f, 'de, T> FromForm<'f> for Message<T> where T: Deserialize<'de>`.

To actually perform the decoding, I:

1. Get the `"json"` key of the form data;
2. URL-decode the value;
3. Parse the JSON contained in the value.

Bailing out as soon as possible. Code doing that (explicit type annotations for the reader's convenience):

```
fn from_form(items: &mut FormItems<'f>, strict: bool) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
    // Get JSON field
    let encoded: Option<&RawStr> = items.find(|&(k, _)| k.as_str() == "json")
        .map(|(_, v)| v);
    if let None = encoded {
        return Err(MessageFormError::MissingJsonKey);
    }

    // Decode URL-string
    let decoded: Result<String, Utf8Error> = encoded.unwrap().url_decode();
    if let Err(e) = decoded {
        return Err(MessageFormError::InvalidUrl(e));
    }

    // Parse JSON
    let json: String = decoded.unwrap();
    serde_json::from_str::<Self>(&json) // Line 205
        .map_err(|e| MessageFormError::InvalidJson(e))
}
```

[A Gist demonstrating the problem](https://gist.github.com/kroltan/f7317173f08a11230930ef1abb8c1e54) in a paste-and-run way (doesn't work on the Playground since it depends on Rocket).

As I understand:

- The `&RawStr` of `encoded` has lifetime `'f`.
- A `String` is created out of it by `url_decode`, which lives until the end of the function
- `serde_json` takes a `&'x str` where `'x` does not need to coincide with `'de`, and returns a value (so it lives to the end of the function, and since it's returned, gets moved beyond it)

But it seems my understanding is incorrect:

```
205 |         serde_json::from_str::<Self>(&json)
    |                                       ^^^^ does not live long enough
206 |             .map_err(|e| MessageFormError::InvalidJson(e))
207 |     }
    |     - borrowed value only lives until here
    |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'f as defined on the impl at 184:1...
   --> src/transport.rs:184:1
    |
184 | / impl<'f, T> FromForm<'f> for Message<T>
185 | |     where T: Deserialize<'f>
186 | | {
187 | |     type Error = MessageFormError;
...   |
207 | |     }
208 | | }
    | |_^
```

What am I getting wrong, and how can I return the deserialized value properly?

Comment: Can you put the code in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.com), so that it can be easily reproduced? At first glance, there seems to be a missing relation between the lifetimes `'f` and `'de`.

Comment: @E_net4 Not quite, since the playground doesn't have the Rocket crate, sadly. I'll make a more complete example that can be pasted into a file.

Comment: @E_net4 Added gist!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**This section of the Serde website covers `Deserialize` bounds in detail.**](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds)

---

> There are two main ways to write `Deserialize` trait bounds, whether
>   on an impl block or a function or anywhere else.
>
> - **`<'de, T> where T: Deserialize<'de>`**
>
>   This means "T can be deserialized from **some** lifetime." The caller gets to decide what lifetime that is. Typically this is used
>     when the caller also provides the data that is being deserialized
>     from, for example in a function like
>     [`serde_json::from_str`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_str.html).
>     In that case the input data must also have lifetime `'de`, for example
>     it could be `&'de str`.
> - **`<T> where T: DeserializeOwned`**
>
>   This means "T can be deserialized from **any** lifetime." The callee gets to decide what lifetime. Usually this is because the data
>     that is being deserialized from is going to be thrown away before the
>     function returns, so T must not be allowed to borrow from it. **In your
>     case the data is coming from URL-decoding some input, and the decoded
>     data is thrown away after deserializing T.** Another common use of this
>     bound is functions that deserialize from an IO stream, such as
>     [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html).
>
>   To say it more technically, the [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html)
>     trait is equivalent to the [higher-rank trait
>     bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html)
>     `for<'de> Deserialize<'de>`. The only difference is `DeserializeOwned` is more
>     intuitive to read. It means T owns all the data that gets
>     deserialized.

Replacing your `T: Deserialize<'f>` bound with `T: DeserializeOwned`
correctly communicates that T is not allowed to borrow from the
URL-decoded data because the URL-decoded data will not outlive T.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. It makes sense that input must outlive output, I didn't realize how the lifetimes were connected from the reference alone. But I have to agree with Shepmaster, please answer the question inline.