# How to specify lifetime for associated type that implements Deserialize

Tags: rust

I have a trait that's defined like this:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

trait MyTrait {    
     type InputDoc: Deserialize; //Error: missing lifetime specifier: expected lifetime parameter
     type OutputDoc: Serialize;

     fn create() -> Self;
     fn process(& self, doc: &Self::InputDoc) -> Self::OutputDoc;  
}
```

I want to use the trait like this:

```
fn run<M: MyTrait>() -> () {
    let mytrait = M::create();

    let data = ...load some string from somewhere ...;
    let doc: serde_json::Result<M::InputDoc> = serde_json::from_str(data);
    let result = mytrait.process(&doc);
}
```

The problem looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734640/how-do-i-specify-lifetime-parameters-in-an-associated-type), but I could not get it to work with the proposed solution. I actually don't get why the lifetime is needed at all, which makes it even harder to figure out the solution. Can somebody explain how to specify a lifetime, that allows my example to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifetime error when creating a function that returns a value implementing serde::Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554679/lifetime-error-when-creating-a-function-that-returns-a-value-implementing-serde/43564347#43564347)

Comment: In short, you can use `DeserializeOwned`, which is effectively a shorthand for the HRTB `for<'de> Deserialize<'de>`.

Comment: This is a pretty common issue; see also [Lifetimes when Deserializing JSON within a FromForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783315/lifetimes-when-deserializing-json-within-a-fromform)